# Why is Google Maps Static Geocoding API showing my 127.0.0.1:8080 IP Address to be invalid?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to enable Google Maps Static Geocoding Maps API on my website as well as my localhost. While it accepts the IP address of my website, my localhost's IP which is 127.0.0.1:8080 is shown to be invalid.

**EDIT**

I am trying to use the API to provide addresses of certain places in backend which will be converted to latitudes and longitudes which will be displayes as markers on the map. There is no user input.

Please help

Comment: add the code, to get the right answer

Comment: What is the Google Maps Static Geocoding Maps API?  Can you point to the documentation?

Comment: @geocodezip Just type Google Maps API in Google and then visit Web Services

Answer (score 0):

IP address 127.0.0.1 (a.k.a. localhost) is a  [reserved IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses) address, so Google can't do any geocoding with it.

Comment: I am new at this but which of Google's Maps APIs can be integrated with localhost ?

Comment: Geocoding is a process that translates an IP address lot a geographical location. For reserved addresses this is not possible because they have no external visibility. Maps API's is another issue, I'm not sure you mean with that. You can of course use the google maps api on your local 127.0.01 machine